# Is it possible to call a future static callout method from a scheduler

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, future, method, static

I have a static callout which i want to schedule every 5 minutes. How would i approach this I have tried the following but the the incorrect signature error:

Callout

```
public class or_service { 
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void  getleads() {
        if(doCallout) {
          Http http = new Http();
          HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
          ..
        }
    }
}
```

Scheduler

```
public class or_scheduleLeads implements Schedulable {
    public void execute(SchedulableContext context) {
        System.abortJob(context.getTriggerId());
        String sch = '0 '+DateTime.now().addMinutes(5).minute()+' */1 ? * *';
        //System.schedule('Name', sch, class);
        System.schedule('or_scheduleLeads-'+DateTime.now(), sch, or_service.getleads());
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds a little [x-y ish](http://xyproblem.info) to me. What are you trying to accomplish every five minutes?

Comment: @DavidReed Pranay explained where my confusion was down below. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method signature of System.schedule is improper,

The correct signature is

```
schedule(jobName, cronExpression, schedulableClassInstance)
```

SO your code will be

```
public class or_scheduleLeads implements Schedulable {
    public void execute(SchedulableContext context) {
        System.abortJob(context.getTriggerId());
        String sch = '0 '+DateTime.now().addMinutes(5).minute()+' */1 ? * *';
        //Calling Future Methods
        or_service.getleads(); 
        System.schedule('or_scheduleLeads-'+DateTime.now(), sch, new or_scheduleLeads()));
    }
}
```

src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_schedule